# Duda sobre React y useState en objetos JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, jsonobject, usestate

Tengo la siguiente App en React que hace el llamado a una APIRest y éste devuelve un JSON con un único objeto

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
const CallToAPI= () => {
const [personasdate, setPersonasdate] = useState([])
const CallApiTip = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await fetch("https;//www.urldelbackend.com/personas")
        const result = await data.json()
        setPersonasdate(result)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    CallToAPI();
}, [])
return (
    <>
        <h2>{personasdate[0].attributes.nombre}</h2>
        <p> {personasdate[0].attributes.cargo}</p>
        <img src={personasdate[0].attributes.perfil_img_data.data.attributes.url} alt="img" />
    </>
)
}
export default CallToAPI
```

El único objeto JSON que devuelve el backend es el siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "nombre": "Juan Fulano de Tal",
      "cargo": "Data Scientist",
             ....
             ...
      "perfil_img_data": {
        "data": {
          "id": 1,
          "attributes": {
            "name": "perfil_1280.jpg",
            "alternativeText": "people_1280.jpg",
                      .....
                      .....
            "width": 30,
            "height": 30,
            "url": "https://urldelaimagen.com/perfil.jpg",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Al ejecutarlo me sale

```
CallToAPI.jsx: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
```

¿por qué sucede esto? como hago el correcto llamado a la APIRest y realizar el renderizado de los atributos que quiero `nombre` , `cargo` y la `url` de la imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problemas es que la petición es asíncrona y react renderiza el componente antes de que tengas los datos de la petición. Tienes que hacer un renderizado condicional que en caso de que no tenga datos pintar nada o algo que diga que estás cargando datos y cuando los tengas, que pinte lo que tu quieres.

El return quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
return (
{personasdate && personasdate.length < 1
    ? <></>
    : <>
        <h2>{personasdate[0].attributes.nombre}</h2>
        <p> {personasdate[0].attributes.cargo}</p>
        <img src={personasdate[0].attributes.perfil_img_data.data.attributes.url} alt="img" />
      </>}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer que te cargue el JSON después de de que carge por completo la pagina

```
window.onload = function() {
  //código a ejecutar
};
```